# Set values in a Pandas column based on identical values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a very large Pandas dataframe in Python that looks something like this:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['file', 'quarter', 'status'])
df_test.file = ['file_1', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_3', 'file_4']
df_test.quarter = [2023q1, 2023q2, 2022q4, 2022q3, 2023q2, 2021q3]
df_test.status = ['', 'kept', '', '', 'kept', '']
```

What I want to do here is to set the 'status' column to equal either 'kept' or 'removed' based on whether those entries in the 'file' column that has an identically named file that already has 'kept' as status. For example, since 'file_1' has one row where 'status' equals 'kept', all entries of 'file_1' should equal 'kept'. The end result of the status column should be:

```
['kept', 'kept', 'removed', 'kept', 'kept', 'removed']
```

Any help on how to do this would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I guess it can help.

```
import pandas as pd

# dataframe
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['file', 'quarter', 'status'])
df_test.file = ['file_1', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_3', 'file_4']
df_test.quarter = ['2023q1', '2023q2', '2022q4', '2022q3', '2023q2', '2021q3']
df_test.status = ['', 'kept', '', '', 'kept', '']

def set_status(status):
    if 'kept' in status.values:
        return 'kept'
    else:
        return 'removed'

# apply the function to each group
df_test['status'] = df_test.groupby('file')['status'].transform(set_status)
```

Or shorter variant:

```
df_test['status'] = df_test.groupby('file')['status'].transform(lambda x: 'kept' if 'kept' in x.values else 'removed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and `any` for test at least one value:

```
df_test['status'] = np.where(df_test['status'].eq('kept')
                                              .groupby(df_test['file'])
                                              .transform('any'),
                             'kept','removed')
print (df_test)
     file quarter   status
0  file_1  2023q1     kept
1  file_1  2023q2     kept
2  file_2  2022q4  removed
3  file_3  2022q3     kept
4  file_3  2023q2     kept
5  file_4  2021q3  removed
```

Or replace non matched values to `NaN`s, use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `first` and last replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df_test['status'] = (df_test['status'].where(df_test['status'].eq('kept'))
                                      .groupby(df_test['file'])
                                      .transform('first')
                                      .fillna('removed'))
print (df_test)
     file quarter   status
0  file_1  2023q1     kept
1  file_1  2023q2     kept
2  file_2  2022q4  removed
3  file_3  2022q3     kept
4  file_3  2023q2     kept
5  file_4  2021q3  removed
```